# image uploading works properly with all devices except iphone

Tags: php, ios, iphone, codeigniter

**php (codeigniter): image uploading working properly in all devices but on working on iphone devices**

**Only iphone-captuered images are getting uploaded, but not working for non-captured/other images**

My Code Snippet:
(too lengthy code, I am just some part of that code)

```
<?php
    .....
    .....  
    $this->load->library("upload");
    $this->upload->initialize($this->set_upload_options()); 

    if($this->upload->do_upload()){

          $ppimagedata = $this -> upload -> data();
          $ppnewimagename = $ppimagedata["file_name"];

          $this -> load -> library("image_lib");
          $config['image_library']   = 'gd2';
          $config['source_image']    = $ppimagedata["full_path"];
          $config['create_thumb']    = TRUE;
          $config['maintain_ratio']  = FALSE;

          $config['new_image']    = './uploads/Property/300X300/';
          $config['width']       = 300;
          $config['height']       = 300;
          $this -> image_lib -> initialize($config);
          $this -> image_lib -> resize();
    }  

    private function set_upload_options() {     
        $config = array ();
        $config ['upload_path'] = './uploads/Property';
        $config ['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';  
        return $config;
    }
    ....
    ....
?>
```

above php (codeigniter) script working properly for all devices but not working for iphone

Please suggest me the changes or idea to resolve this issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29733722/image-upload-not-working-in-codeigniter check this out may be it will helpful to you.

Comment: I also "tft|TFT" added in allowed types.. but though its not working

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710352/codeigniter-image-upload-cant-get-error-message-to-show

check this out to find error at upload time may be putting code of show error will help you to find out what issue you are facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In windows or android..  "jpg" auto-consider as "jpeg". But for iPhone, you have to mention it separately in "allow-types"